# Set system path for CMD on Windows 8.1: Trying to override Windows/System32/find.exe

Tags: windows, cmd, mingw, windows-8.1, msys

I'm trying to override the windows `find` command, so that I can call another implementation of `find`.  The other implementation is provided by MSYS and located in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin.  On Windows 7, I can open up a CMD, and run:

```
SET PATH=C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;%PATH%
```

Since that prefixes the MSYS path before the C:\Windows\System32\ path, when `find` is called within CMD on Windows 7, the MSYS version executes.

That command doesn't work with Windows 8.1.  When I call `find` in CMD on Windows 8.1, it defaults to the Windows implementation no matter what I do.  Is there a way to override it on Windows 8.1?

I'm looking for a solution that only changes the path information of the current CMD instance.  For my purposes, I'd rather not have to use powershell (even though the path setting works as expected in powershell).

Thanks!

Comment: What does it say when you enter `where find` on the Windows 8.1 box? What about when you enter `c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin\find`?

Comment: After setting the path, where find returns:
"C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\find.exe"  So it's finding both, but the windows has precedence.  Using the absolute path for the MSYS find executes the MSYS version.  I just don't have the option of specifying the absolute path with the code I'm using.  (I'm using a build system that assumes find executes the MSYS-style find.)

Comment: Hmm... weird. If you type `PATH` after changing the path does it show the old or new value?

Comment: Just a thought, check the registry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths" and see if you have an entry for find.exe

Comment: Also, try doskey /macros from a cmd prompt just in case.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Learned some new tricks from you both that will help down the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run cmd.exe, make sure that you are not running the command from the C:\Windows\System32 directory (that's where it opens automatically for me).  When you are in a directory with a matching command (in this case MS' find.exe) that local copy will take precedence over your PATH variable, even if your MSYS find.exe is listed first in the path.

So, to get it to work for me I run cmd.exe, then

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET PATH=C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
```

If I run `where find` I get

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\msys64\usr\bin\find.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\find.exe
```

If I change directories and run `where find` I get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\
C:\>where find
C:\msys64\usr\bin\find.exe
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\find.exe
```

My path is slightly different because I'm trying this with MSYS2, but the same should apply to the older version of MSYS.

Good luck @mikewesthad!

Comment: Well now.  That's an easy fix.  Here I was blaming windows 8...rather than reading my default cmd path.  Thanks!